# Python epoc time to hour only?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given epoch time like 1491021658 in Python what is the direct way to get the hour (without minutes) in military time?

example

```
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1491021658))
'2017-04-01 00:40:58'
```

get only 00

using Python 3.5.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, if you want only hours, use `%H` only.

```
time.strftime('%H', time.localtime(1491021658))
```